# Divi child theme refuse override parent CSS - body

Tags: php, css, wordpress, parent-child

if this question is duplicate of some other, i do apologize. But i am not able to find the right answer.
I am building some web page. I use Divi theme via WordPress. I've created child theme of Divi theme.
I've attached custom style.css via function.php in child theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', 
get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
```

But when I want to change some main elements, like body{}, it does not override parent style. Mine actual customization process is:

1. Find which id/class have the element, which i wanna change.
2. Via additional CSS in the theme customize the element with class/id I've found.
3. Hope that it will have the exact behavior I want.

I can't find any good source to learn how this all parent->child customization works and I struggle with basic things. Can you help me, how to easily change many elements of parent's theme?
Any help would be nice. Thank you guys!

Edit: There is code from site:
[site_inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSSjM.png)

And there is code in my css:

```
body.custom-background {
background-image: url("images/pozadie_B5.png");
background-color: black;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center -25%;
}
```

When i place this in Additional CSS in THEME customizer, then it works. But in style.css in my child theme it does not.

Comment: That code you posted is correct compared to my current child theme.  What I would recommend is taking a screenshot of your web inspector so we can see the current code for the element you're trying to change.  Then post your new css so we can verify that you're using the correct code and selector.

Comment: @Eric first thing first, i am trying to change whole element body{} to override parents one. Like background-image, bacground-color, fonts, etc. I will edit post and add asked elements.

Comment: Did you activate your child theme after creating it?  Did you verify that your child theme folder is in the themes folder?

Comment: Yes, i've did. Child theme works, or it looks like. I've manage to change few things, but i cant get to many classes and IDs from CSS.

Comment: I am just confused. Many things added via Theme costomizing - Additional CSS works (it shows actual change of site). But same code added to mine style.css doesn't make any change.

Comment: I understand it very well can be.  For instance, .this-class.that-class does not mean the same as .this-class .that-class.  If you're trying to make changes to the body but seeing no changes, you may not be overriding the correct selector.  For instance, a style might be on the body tag but applied using the class main-page.  If you try to override using body rather than .main-page you may not see a change.  Check out this example I made you, run it, then move the block of css I indicated in the comment.  You'll see exactly what I'm talking about. https://jsfiddle.net/s3m7vf8v/1/

Comment: You may not notice my comment inside the jsfiddle, it's in the css panel at line 14.  The example shows that adding margin with .body does not override div.body.  This may be the issue you're having.

Comment: I've just read your updated question.  From what I've read, the theme customizer saves your custom css in a database and so adding css directly to style.css may have adverse effects.  It's not recommended but you could try to force your styling by adding !important to your styles.  Or since you know it works, just use the theme customizer.